# Link not working on website? Cannot mouse over

Tags: html, css

Website is: http://www.talons-guild.com/forums/

Please try to click the link on the left side that says "Home"--it does not work for me. Any idea why?

Comment: The `<div id="header">` is on top of it (that's why you can't click it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it by removing the `z-index` property from `div#header` on your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Because your div with ID of header is on top of it with a higher z-index, which essentially blocks it. Give your paragraph with class menu a higher z-index (and a position) and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The Header Div Container  witch include bird size over the text and it z-index over it too so change size or z-index for item menu

```
<a style='z-index:10;' href="http://www.talons-guild.com/index.php">Home</a><br />
```

regard's